# Bash script for processing directories (REGEX)

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I can't seem to get the regex in my bash script to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/lib/gitolite/repositories
for D in *; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        if [["${D}" = [^[0-9A-Za-z\-_].git$] ]]; then
            echo "${D}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Possible names of directories:

```
test.git
test-admin12.git
test_admin.git
test_admin.git.bkp (these are the folders I DON'T want)
```

I don't want to launch a secondary process like: sed or grep or ls

Comment: If `^[0-9A-Za-z\-_].git$` is a regex, then it only matches `<BOS> 1 character + any char + 'git' <EOS>`. Probably needs to be `^[0-9A-Za-z\-_]+\.git$` if its a regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me (slight change to your if statement):

```
for D in *; do
    if [ -d "${D}" ]; then
        if [[ ^[0-9A-Za-z_-]*\.git$ ]]; then
            echo "${D}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: thank you this worked with a slight modification to the regex:
^[0-9A-Za-z_-]*\.git$

Comment: It matches `.git` also, don't know if that is desired or not.

Comment: @anubhava The `for D in *; do` will not include `.git` so it is not a problem.

Comment: @user1454770 - Both styles functioned for me, but I have updated my answer to match what worked for you.

Comment: the . in regex is any character I wanted to make sure the folder finished in ".git" not just "git"

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
if [["${D}" = [^[0-9A-Za-z\-_].git$] ]]; then
   echo "${D}"
fi
```

Use this condition with correct syntax and correct regex:

```
[[ "${D}" =~ ^[0-9A-Za-z_-]+\.git$ ]] && echo "${D}"
```

Comment: It still outputs nothing

Answer (score 1):

You can write a single glob to match valid directories if you enable extended patterns.

```
shopt -s extglob
for D in +([[:alnum:]_-]).git/; do
    echo "$D"
done
```

The notation `+(...)` matches one or more of the enclosed pattern. The brackets match one of a single alphanumeric character, an underscore, or a hyphen (which does not need to be escaped if it is the last character in the brackets). The trailing slash limits matches to directories.

Comment: +1 Simple and clean solution. Thanks for the `*/` tips for matching only directories. Where is that documented?

Comment: @Herman Torjussen - That might be a literal / and part of the regex, but I don't know.

Comment: I'm not sure it's where it's explicitly documented, but I think it's follows from the fact that `/` is not a valid character for a file name, being the directory separator, so it only makes sense for it to indicate that the previous path component is a directory name; with nothing following the `/`, it matches the directory itself, not any of its contents.